# using weka in command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, classpath, weka

I am trying to use weka in command line but I could not even get started. I am having this error;

```
$ java weka.core.Instances data/soybean.arff

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/core/Instances
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.core.Instances
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: weka.core.Instances. Program will exit.
```

As I googled, I think it is something about classpath but I am not familiar even these things. I used weka on windows machine and I need to get used to linux systems (I am newbie on linux). So, please explain in detail.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its not a standard terminal that you should be using.  Rather, **when you are in the "Weka GUI Chooser" you should select the bottom option "Simple CLI"**.  This will open up the appropriate interface.

[image: The bottom option is the one you want.]

Comment: I'm sorry I may have misread your question!  This would work for Windows or Mac, but I'm not sure if this applies to Linux.

Comment: Yes, it works for Linux and seems cool :) But I want to use it on standart terminal. Isn't that possible? Or if it is possible in Python? I tried both of them, always having same problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how you can use it from a standard terminal (at least I've never figured it out)!  You can definitely use it in Java code, and here is a link about using it from Python, http://weka.wikispaces.com/Can+I+use+WEKA+from+Python%3F.

Comment: I know that. But when I try to use it, I am having same problem. Also, when I open weka it is giving errors "Trying to add database driver (JDBC): RmiJdbc.RJDriver - Error, not in CLASSPATH?"

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but to avoid misinformation, `weka` can be used from the normal `bash` shell that most Linux distros include. It is important that you add the weka jar file to your CLASSPATH environment variable. This is done by opening the file `.profile` or other file in your home directory (different operating systems name this file differently). This file should already have at least a few lines with `export` statements. If there is already a line that says `export CLASSPATH="....`, then you just need to add the path to `weka.jar` to that list, which is `:`-delimited. If not, then you need to add a line, like this:

```
export CLASSPATH="/path/to/weka.jar"
```

Restart your shell, and the examples in the weka documentation `WekaManual.pdf` should work just fine.